# C# ListView simplified

Tags: c#, listview

For example:

```
listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1]
```

Shows like:

```
ListViewItem{ OBJECTNAMELOL }
```

I know i can just replace the `ListViewItem{ }`

But is there an easier way which shows it just without it?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted (check box) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Terribly asked question...but I think what you're looking for is:

```
listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text;
```

Comment: Thanks mate i was looking for this soo much :D